# How could I generate my abstract tree using this makefile? Why I see only an error at 1 line?

Tags: makefile, yacc, lex

def.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef enum 
{
  NPROGRAM,
  NVARDECLLIST,
  NFUNCDECLLIST,
  NVARDECL,
  NIDLIST,
  NOPTPARAMLIST,
  NSTATLIST,
  NASSIGNSTAT,
  NWHILESTAT,
  NIFSTAT,
  NFORSTAT,
  NRELEXPR,
  NRETURNSTAT,
  NREADSTAT,
  NLOGICEXPR,
  NWRITESTAT,
  NNEGEXPR,
  NFUNCCALL,
  NEXPRLIST,
  NCONDEXPR,
  NPARAMDECL,
  NMATHEXPR,
  NCASTING
} Nonterminal;


typedef enum
{
  T_BREAK,
  T_TYPE,
  T_BOOLEAN,
  T_INTCONST,
  T_REALCONST,
  T_BOOLCONST,
  T_WRITEOP,
  T_STRCONST,
  T_ID,
  T_NONTERMINAL
} Typenode;


typedef union
{
  int ival;
  float rval;
  char *sval;
  enum {FALSE, TRUE} bval;
} Value;

typedef struct snode
{
  Typenode type;
  Value value;
  struct snode *p1, *p2, *p3;
} Node;

typedef Node *Pnode;


char *newstring(char*);

int yylex();

Pnode nontermnode(Nonterminal, int),
      ntn(Nonterminal),
      idnode(), 
      keynode(Typenode, int), 
      intconstnode(),
      realconstnode(),
      strconstnode(),
      boolconstnode(),
      newnode(Typenode);


void yyerror(),
     treeprint(Pnode, int);
```

lexer.lex

```
%{ 
#include "parser.h"                                                             
#include "def.h"
int line = 1;                                                   
Value lexval;
%}                                                              
%option noyywrap

spacing     ([ \t])+
commento    "#"(.)*\n
letter      [A-Za-z]
digit       [0­9]
intconst    {digit}+
strconst    \"([^\"])*\"
boolconst   false|true
realconst   {intconst}\.{digit}+
id          {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
sugar       [ \( \) : , ; \. \+ \- \* / ]
%%
{spacing}   ;
\n          {line++;}
integer     {return(INTEGER);} 
string      {return(STRING);}
boolean     {return(BOOLEAN);}
real        {return(REAL);}
void        {return(VOID);}
func        {return(FUNC);}
body        {return(BODY);}     
end         {return(END);}
else        {return(ELSE);}
while       {return(WHILE);}
do          {return(DO);}
for         {return(FOR);}
to          {return(TO);}
return      {return(RETURN);}
read        {return(READ);}
write       {return(WRITE);}
writeln     {return(WRITELN);}
and         {return(AND);}
or          {return(OR);}
not         {return(NOT);}
if          {return(IF);}
then        {return(THEN);}
break       {return(BREAK);}    
"<="        {return(LEQ);}
">="        {return(GEQ);}  
"!="        {return(NEQ);}
"=="        {return(EQU);}
"<"         {return(LT);}
">"         {return(GT);}
{intconst}  {lexval.ival = atoi(yytext); return(INTCONST);}
{strconst}  {lexval.sval = newstring(yytext); return(STRCONST);}
{boolconst} {lexval.bval = (yytext[0] == 'f' ? FALSE : TRUE); return(BOOLCONST);}
{realconst} {lexval.rval = atof(yytext); return(REALCONST);}
{id}        {lexval.sval = newstring(yytext); return(ID);}
{sugar}     {return(yytext[0]);}
.           {return(ERROR);}
%%
char *newstring(char *s)
{
  char *p;

  p = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
  strcpy(p, s);
  return(p);
}
```

makefile

```
bup: lexer.o parser.o tree.o
    cc -g -o bup lexer.o parser.o tree.o

lexer.o: lexer.c parser.h def.h
    cc -g -c lexer.c 

parser.o: parser.c def.h
    cc -g -c parser.c

tree.o: tree.c def.h
    cc -g -c tree.c

lexer.c: lexer.lex parser.y parser.h parser.c def.h
    flex -o lexer.c lexer.lex

parser.h: parser.y def.h
    bison -vd -o parser.c parser.y
```

parser.y

```
%{
#include "def.h"
#define YYSTYPE Pnode
extern char *yytext;
extern Value lexval;
extern int line;
extern FILE *yyin;
Pnode root = NULL;
%}
%token ID FUNC  BODY    END     BREAK   IF  THEN    ELSE    TYPE    WHILE   DO  FOR     RETURN      READ    WRITE   WRITELN
%token      AND     OR  INTCONST    REALCONST   BOOLCONST   STRCONST    INTEGER     REAL    NOT  STRING  BOOLEAN  VOID  PLUS  MINUS  TIMES  SLASH
%token  LEQ  GEQ  NEQ  EQU  GT  LT  TO  ERROR
%%
program         :  var-decl-list func-decl-list body '.'    {root = $$ = ntn(NPROGRAM);
                                                            root->p1 = ntn(NVARDECLLIST);
                                                            root->p2 = ntn(NFUNCDECLLIST);
                                                            root->p1->p1 = $1;
                                                            root->p2->p1 = $2;
                                                            root->p3 = $3;}
                ;

var-decl-list   :  var-decl var-decl-list                   {$$ -> p1=$1;
                                                            $1->p3=$2;}
                |                                           {$$ = NULL;}
                ;

var-decl        :  id-list ':' type ';'                     {$$ = ntn(NVARDECL);
                                                            $$ -> p1 = ntn(NIDLIST);
                                                            $$->p1->p1=$1; $$ -> p1 -> p3 = $3;}
                ;

id-list         : ID {$$ = idnode();} ',' id-list           {$$ = $2;
                                                            $2 -> p3 = $4;} 
                | ID                                        {$$ = idnode();}
                ;

type            : INTEGER                                   {$$ = keynode(T_TYPE, INTEGER);}
                | REAL                                      {$$ = keynode(T_TYPE, REAL);}
                | STRING                                    {$$ = keynode(T_TYPE, STRING);}

                | BOOLEAN                                   {$$ = keynode(T_TYPE, BOOLEAN);}

                | VOID                                      {$$ = keynode(T_TYPE, VOID); }

                ;

func-decl-list  : func-decl func-decl-list                  {$$ -> p1 = $1;
                                                            $1 -> p3 = $2;}
                |                                           {$$ = NULL;}
                ;

func-decl       : FUNC ID {$$ = idnode();} '(' opt-param-list ')' ':' type var-decl-list body ';'       {$$ -> p1 = $3;
                                                                                                        $$ -> p2 = ntn(NOPTPARAMLIST);
                                                                                                        $$ -> p2 ->p1=$5;
                                                                                                        $$ -> p2 -> p3 = $8;
                                                                                                        $$ -> p2 -> p3->p3 = ntn(NVARDECLLIST);
                                                                                                        $$ -> p2 -> p3->p3->p1 = $9;
                                                                                                        $$ -> p2 -> p3->p3->p3 = $10;} 
                ;

opt-param-list  : param-list                                {$$ = $1;}
                |                                           {$$ = NULL;}
                ;

param-list      : param-decl ',' param-list                 {$$ = $1;
                                                            $1 -> p3 = $3;}
                | param-decl                                
                ;

param-decl      : ID {$$ = idnode();} ':' type              {$$=ntn(NPARAMDECL);
                                                            $$ -> p1 = $2;
                                                            $$ -> p2 = $4;}
                ;

body            : BODY stat-list END                        {$$ = ntn(NSTATLIST);
                                                            $$->p1=$2;}
                ;

stat-list       : stat ';' stat-list                        {$$ = $1;
                                                            $1 -> p3 = $3;}
                | stat  ';'                                 {$$=$1;}
                ;
stat            : assign-stat                               
                | if-stat                                   
                | while-stat                                
                | for-stat                                  
                | return-stat                               
                | read-stat                                 
                | write-stat                                
                | func-call                                 
                | BREAK                                     {$$ = newnode(T_BREAK);}
                ;

assign-stat     : ID {$$ = idnode();} '=' expr              {$$ = ntn(NASSIGNSTAT);
                                                            $$ -> p1 = $2;
                                                            $$ -> p2 = $4;}
                ;

if-stat         : IF expr THEN stat-list opt-else-stat END  {$$ = ntn(NIFSTAT);
                                                            $$ -> p1 = $2;
                                                            $$ -> p2 = ntn(NSTATLIST);
                                                            $$ ->p2 -> p3 = $5;}
                ;

opt-else-stat   : ELSE stat-list                            {$$ = ntn(NSTATLIST);
                                                            $$->p1=$2;}
                |                                           {$$ = NULL;}
                ;

while-stat      : WHILE expr DO stat-list END               {$$ = ntn(NWHILESTAT);
                                                            $$->p1=$2;
                                                            $$->p2=ntn(NSTATLIST);
                                                            $$->p2->p1=$4;}
                ;       

for-stat        : FOR ID {$$=idnode();} '=' expr TO expr DO stat-list END   {$$ = ntn(NFORSTAT);
                                                                            $$->p1=$3;
                                                                            $$->p2=$5;
                                                                            $$->p2->p3=$7;
                                                                            $$->p2->p3->p3=ntn(NSTATLIST);
                                                                            $$->p2->p3->p3->p1=$9;}
                ;

return-stat     : RETURN opt-expr                           {$$ = ntn(NRETURNSTAT);
                                                            $$->p1=$2;}
                ;

opt-expr        : expr                                      {$$=$1;}
                |                                           {$$=NULL;}
                ;

read-stat       : READ '(' id-list ')'                      {$$ = ntn(NREADSTAT);
                                                            $$->p1=ntn(NIDLIST);
                                                            $$->p1->p1=$3;}
                ;

write-stat      : write-op '(' expr-list ')'                {$$ = ntn(NWRITESTAT);
                                                            $$->p1=$1;
                                                            $$->p2=ntn(NEXPRLIST);
                                                            $$->p2->p1=$3;}
                ;

write-op        : WRITE                                     {$$ = keynode(T_WRITEOP, WRITE);}

                | WRITELN                                   {$$ = keynode(T_WRITEOP, WRITELN);}

                ;

expr-list       : expr ',' expr-list                        {$$=$1;
                                                            $1->p3=$3;}
                | expr
                ;

expr            : expr logic-op bool-term                   { $$=$2;
                                                            $2->p1=$1;
                                                            $2->p2=$3;}
                | bool-term                                 
                ;

logic-op        : AND                                       {$$=nontermnode(NLOGICEXPR, AND);}

                | OR                                        {$$=nontermnode(NLOGICEXPR, OR);}

                ;

bool-term       : rel-term rel-op rel-term                  {$$=$2;
                                                            $2->p1=$1;
                                                            $2->p2=$3;}
                | rel-term
                ;
rel-op          : EQU                                   {$$=nontermnode(NRELEXPR, EQU);}

                | NEQ                                   {$$=nontermnode(NRELEXPR, NEQ);}

                | GT                                        {$$=nontermnode(NRELEXPR, GT);}

                | GEQ                                   {$$=nontermnode(NRELEXPR, GEQ);}

                | LT                                        {$$=nontermnode(NRELEXPR, LT);}

                | LEQ                                   {$$=nontermnode(NRELEXPR, LEQ);}

                ;
rel-term        : rel-term low-prec-op low-term             {$$=$2;
                                                            $2->p1=$1;
                                                            $2->p2=$3;}
                | low-term
                ;

low-prec-op     : PLUS                                      {$$=nontermnode(NMATHEXPR, PLUS);}

                | MINUS                                     {$$=nontermnode(NMATHEXPR, MINUS);}

                ;   

low-term        : low-term high-prec-op factor              {$$=$2;
                                                            $2->p1=$1;
                                                            $2->p2=$3;}
                | factor
                ;

high-prec-op    : TIMES                                         {$$=nontermnode(NMATHEXPR, TIMES);}

                | SLASH                                     {$$=nontermnode(NMATHEXPR, SLASH);}

                ;

factor          : unary-op factor                           {$$=$1;
                                                            $1->p3=$2;}
                | '(' expr ')'                              {$$=$2;}
                | ID                                        {$$=idnode();}
                | const                                     {$$=$1;}
                | func-call                                 {$$=$1;}
                | cond-expr                                 {$$=$1;}
                | cast '(' expr ')'                         {$$=$1;
                                                            $1->p3=$3;}
                ;

unary-op        : MINUS                                         {$$=nontermnode(NNEGEXPR, MINUS);}

                | NOT                                       {$$=nontermnode(NNEGEXPR, NOT);}

                ;   

const           : INTCONST                                  {$$=intconstnode();}
                | REALCONST                                 {$$=realconstnode();}
                | STRCONST                                  {$$=strconstnode();}
                | BOOLCONST                                 {$$=boolconstnode();}
                ;

func-call       : ID {$$=idnode();} '(' opt-expr-list ')'   {$$ = ntn(NFUNCCALL);
                                                            $$->p1=$2; $$->p2=$4;}
                ;

opt-expr-list   : expr-list                                 {$$=ntn(NEXPRLIST); $$->p1=$1;}
                |                                           {$$=NULL;}
                ;

cond-expr       : IF expr THEN expr ELSE expr END           {$$=ntn(NCONDEXPR);
                                                            $$->p1=$2;
                                                            $$->p2=$4;
                                                            $$->p3=$6;}
                ;

cast            : INTEGER                                   {$$=nontermnode(NCASTING,INTEGER);}

                | REAL                                      {$$=nontermnode(NCASTING, REAL);}

                ;
%%      

Pnode ntn(Nonterminal nonterm)
{
    Pnode p = newnode(T_NONTERMINAL);
    p->value.rval = nonterm;
    return(p);
}

Pnode nontermnode(Nonterminal nonterm, int valore)
{
    Pnode p = newnode(T_NONTERMINAL);
    p->value.rval = nonterm;
    p->value.ival = valore;
    return(p);
}

Pnode idnode()
{
    Pnode p = newnode(T_ID);
    p->value.sval = lexval.sval;
    return(p);
}

Pnode keynode(Typenode keyword, int valore)
{
    Pnode p = newnode(keyword);
    p->value.ival = valore;
    return p;
}

Pnode intconstnode()
{
    Pnode p = newnode(T_INTCONST);
    p->value.ival = lexval.ival;
    return(p);
}

Pnode realconstnode()
{
    Pnode p = newnode(T_REALCONST);
    p->value.rval = lexval.rval;
    return(p);
}

Pnode strconstnode()
{
    Pnode p = newnode(T_STRCONST);
    p->value.sval = lexval.sval;
    return(p);
}

Pnode boolconstnode()
{
  Pnode p = newnode(T_BOOLCONST);
  p->value.bval = lexval.bval;
  return(p);
}

Pnode newnode(Typenode tnode)
{
  Pnode p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  p->type = tnode;
  p->p1 = p->p2 = p->p3 = NULL;
  return(p);
}

int main()
{
  int result;
  printf("----------------------------------------------");
  yyin = stdin;
  if((result = yyparse()) == 0)
    treeprint(root, 0);
  return(result);
}

void yyerror()
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Line %d: syntax error on symbol \"%s\"\n",
          line, yytext);
  exit(-1);
}
```

tree.c

```
#include "def.h"

char* tabtypes[] =
{
  "T_BREAK",
  "T_TYPE",
  "T_BOOLEAN",
  "T_INTCONST",
  "T_REALCONST",
  "T_BOOLCONST",
  "T_WRITEOP",
  "T_STRCONST",
  "T_ID",
  "T_NONTERMINAL"
};

char* tabnonterm[] =
{
  "PROGRAM",
  "NVARDECLLIST",
  "NFUNCDECLLIST",
  "NVARDECL",
  "NIDLIST",
  "NOPTPARAMLIST",
  "NSTATLIST",
  "NASSIGNSTAT",
  "NWHILESTAT",
  "NIFSTAT",
  "NFORSTAT",
  "NRELEXPR",
  "NRETURNSTAT",
  "NREADSTAT",
  "NLOGICEXPR",
  "NWRITESTAT",
  "NNEGEXPR",
  "NFUNCCALL",
  "NEXPRLIST",
  "NCONDEXPR",
  "NPARAMDECL",
  "NMATHEXPR",
  "NCASTING"
};

void treeprint(Pnode root, int indent)
{

  int i;
  Pnode p;

  for(i=0; i<indent; i++)
    printf("    ");
  printf("%s", (root->type == T_NONTERMINAL ? tabnonterm[root->value.ival] : tabtypes[root->type]));
  if(root->type == T_ID || root->type == T_STRCONST)
    printf(" (%s)", root->value.sval);
  else if(root->type == T_INTCONST)
    printf(" (%d)", root->value.ival);
  else if(root->type == T_BOOLCONST)
    printf(" (%s)", (root->value.ival == TRUE ? "true" : "false"));
  printf("\n");
  for(p=root->p1; p != NULL; p = p->p3)
    treeprint(p, indent+1);
}
```

prog ( File with example of grammar)

```
numero: integer;
func fattoriale(n: integer): integer
  fact: integer;
body
  if n == 0 then
    fact = 1;
  else
    fact = n * fattoriale(n­1);
  end;
  return fact;
end;
func stampaFattoriali(tot: integer): void
  i, f: integer;
body
  for i=0 to tot do
    f = fattoriale(i);
    writeln("Il fattoriale di ", i, "è ", f);
  end;
end;
body
  read(numero);
  if numero < 0 then
    writeln("Il numero ", numero, "non è valido");
  else
    stampaFattoriali(numero);
end.
```

When i type make on terminal , it create the files : tree.o parser.o parser.h parser.c lexer.c lexer.o bup.

When i execute the bup file , the terminal show me this error message :

```
"ine 1: syntax error on symbol "
```

So it don't generate the abstract tree.

I don't know if this error refers to the prog or lexer.lex or parse.y file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yacc/bison assign their own numbers to terminal tokens, and assume that the lexer will use those numbers. But you provide your own numbers in the `def.h` header, which yacc/bison knows absolutely nothing about. It will not correctly interpret the codes returned by `yylex` which will make it impossible to parse correctly.

So don't do that.

Let bison generate the token codes, use the header file it generates (`parser.h` with your settings), and don't step on its feet by trying to define the enum values yourself.

As a hint about debugging, that is really way too much code to have written before you start debugging, and that fact is exactly illustrated by your complaint at the end of your question that you don't know where to look for the error. Instead of writing the whole project and then hoping it works as a whole, write little pieces and debug them as you go. Although you need to parser to generate the token type values, you don't need to run the parser to test your scanner. You can write a simple program which repeatedly calls `yylex` and prints the returned types and values. (Or you can just enable flex debugging with the `-d` command line option, which is even simpler.)

Similarly, you should be able to test your AST methods by writing some test functions which use these methods to build, walk and print out an AST. Make sure that they produce the expected results.

Only once you have evidence that the lexer is producing the correct tokens and that your AST construction functions work should you start to debug your parser. Again, you will find it much easier if you use the built-in debugging facilities; see the [Debugging your parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Debugging) section of the Bison manual for instructions.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Step by step and with the debugger I solved many errors.

Comment: Excuse me , I've another question : I run the debugger and I see that the problem is the end of line. Thanks

Comment: I guess your input file has Windows line endings. You might want to change your end of line patten from `\n` (which only recognises unix line endings) to `\r?\n` (which should deal with both possibilities).

Comment: @StefanoVerdina: but that's just a guess because I can't see over your shoulder and you're not revealing much of what you see.